# Issues Regarding Quartus Synthesis Running Time

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim, intel-fpga, quartus

I am running Quartus II 13.0sp1 (64-bit) Web Edition. I used to design my modules in ModelSim simulator. Unfortunately, when I tried to test my program using the Altera Kit via Quartus II 13.0sp1. It takes so long time to run the program. Beside the fact that my operating system is Windows 8, and I am running it on my MacBook Pro 2.5 GHz i5.

Here is my library, entity and some of my architecture  :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity PrimeTest is
port( SW: in std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);
KEY: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
LEDG: out std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
LEDR: out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0));
end PrimeTest;  

Architecture Behavior1 of PrimeTest is
signal Binary_N: std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);
signal Binary_M: std_logic_vector(17 downto 0); 
signal integer_M: integer;
signal Binary_E: std_logic_vector(17 downto 0); 
signal Integer_N: integer;
signal Integer_R: integer;
signal binary_R: std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);
signal Test1 : std_logic ;
```

I am actually running my program by using function and some of them are impure (which my be the cause of this problem!). However, this is the calling of my function:

```
Begin
integer_M <= Integer_Binary(SW) WHEN KEY = "1110";
test1 <= IS_Prime(integer_M)WHEN KEY = "0111";
LEDG(8) <= test1; 
WITH KEY  SELECT
LEDR <= SW WHEN "1110",
(others=>'0') WHEN OTHERS;          
end Behavior1;
```

Comment: What is a "long time"? What do you expect? Synthesis and especially the Fitter are slow in general, from a few minutes for simple designs on small FPGAs to many hours for complex designs on larger FPGAs.

Comment: My program is not that complicated.It is only a Rabin Miller primality testing for 32-bit. However, it took more than one day!!

Comment: Quartus 13 is pretty fast, but it needs a big CPU and lots of memory.Make sure you have virtual memory set up correct on your PC, defrag your hard drive and run quartus without any other applications running. It should not take more than half an hour or so to synthesize your design. P&R can take longer but it is all relative, FPGA synthesis and P&R always takes 100s of times more than simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say your first problem is Windows-8 with Quartus. Unless they fixed it very recently you're stuck in 32-bit mode using only one core.  If you could drop-back to Windows-7 on a multi-core machine and use the 64-bit Quartus (and a lot of memory, my machine has an i7 and 32G of RAM).